# Kafka Listener rollback transaction on session timeout

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using `spring-kafka` version `1.1.3` to consume messages from a topic. Auto commit is set to `true` and `max.poll.records` to `10` in the consumer config. `session.timeout.ms` is negotiated to 10 seconds with the server.

Upon receiving a message I persist part of it to the database. My database tends to be quite slow sometimes, which results in a session timeout by the kafka listener:

> Auto offset commit failed for group mygroup: Commit cannot be completed
>   since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to
>   another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to
>   poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which
>   typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message
>   processing. You can address this either by increasing the session
>   timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll()
>   with max.poll.records.

Since I can't increase the session timeout on the server and the `max.poll.records` is already down at 10, I'd like to be able to wrap my database call in a transaction, which would rollback in case of a kafka session timeout.

Is this possible and how can I accomplish this?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution in the docs.

Comment: Why rollback the DB commit? If you need to just set the consumer to manual commits and then catch the exception.

Comment: What exception? Above message is only logged. As far as I know, there is no exception thrown when the kafka session times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to upgrade to Kafka 0.11 since it adds transaction support (see [Release Notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.11.0.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider to upgrade to Spring Kafka `1.2` and Kafka `0.10.x`. The old Apache Kafka has a flaw with the heart-beat. So, using `autoCommit` and slow listener you end up with unexpected rebalancing and you are on your own with such a problem. The version of Spring Kafka you use has a logic like:

```
// if the container is set to auto-commit, then execute in the
// same thread
// otherwise send to the buffering queue
if (this.autoCommit) {
    invokeListener(records);
}
else {
    if (sendToListener(records)) {
        if (this.assignedPartitions != null) {
            // avoid group management rebalance due to a slow
            // consumer
            this.consumer.pause(this.assignedPartitions);
            this.paused = true;
            this.unsent = records;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you may consider to switch off the `autoCommit` and rely on the built-in `pause` feature which is turned on by default.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: @meva , does it work for you? It’s really good manner to accept answers to let others to know that here is a solution